# "Settings" for a function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Wasn't sure exactly what to call this, but consider the following example:

```
def example():
    """ Nice """
    pass
```

If I were to `print example.__doc__`, it would output `" Nice "`. My question is, is there any way to set more 'variables' like this for other uses I may have?

Comment: You can add arbitrary attributes to a function, but note that the leading-and-trailing-double-underscore combination should be considered reserved for Python internal usage.

Comment: I think your question is pretty ambiguous. Do provide a clearer description @blk.

Answer (score 4):

In Python functions are first-class objects and as such you can add variables to them. See [PEP-232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) for more details on function attributes.

```
def foo():
    pass

foo.abc = 'abc'

print(foo.abc)
# 'abc'
```

You could set the attribute in the function definition itself, but it will only be "set" once the function has been run at least once, as the below example shows.

```
def foo():
    foo.abc = 'abc'

print(foo.abc)
# AttributeError as the attribute hasn't been assigned yet.

foo()

print(foo.abc)
# 'abc'
```

Finally, you could use a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) to add function attributes if you so wish, this has the advantage that you don't need to run the function once. An example would be

```
def add_abc(func):
    # Adds an attribute to a defined function.
    func.abc = 'abc'
    return func

@add_abc
def my_function():
    pass

print(my_function.abc)
# 'abc'
```

Comment: Is there no way at all to add them within the function?